# How to make the planner tolerate init score

Tags: java, optimization, optaplanner

I have taken the cloud balancing problem to a different direction:

A problem where you need to fill up all the computers with processes and computers can overfill (by changing the overfill constraint to a soft one)

The change was easy by adding the following constraints:

```
Constraint unfilledCpuPowerTotal(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
    return constraintFactory.forEach(CloudProcess.class)
            .groupBy(CloudProcess::getComputer, sum(CloudProcess::getRequiredCpuPower))
            .filter((computer, requiredCpuPower) -> requiredCpuPower < computer.getCpuPower())
            .penalize("unfilledCpuPowerTotal",
                    HardSoftScore.ONE_HARD,
                    (computer, requiredCpuPower) -> computer.getCpuPower() - requiredCpuPower);
}

Constraint unfilledMemoryTotal(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
    return constraintFactory.forEach(CloudProcess.class)
            .groupBy(CloudProcess::getComputer, sum(CloudProcess::getRequiredMemory))
            .filter((computer, requiredMemory) -> requiredMemory < computer.getMemory())
            .penalize("unfilledMemoryTotal",
                    HardSoftScore.ONE_HARD,
                    (computer, requiredMemory) -> computer.getMemory() - requiredMemory);
}

Constraint unfilledNetworkBandwidthTotal(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
    return constraintFactory.forEach(CloudProcess.class)
            .groupBy(CloudProcess::getComputer, sum(CloudProcess::getRequiredNetworkBandwidth))
            .filter((computer, requiredNetworkBandwidth) -> requiredNetworkBandwidth < computer.getNetworkBandwidth())
            .penalize("unfilledNetworkBandwidthTotal",
                    HardSoftScore.ONE_HARD,
                    (computer, requiredNetworkBandwidth) -> computer.getNetworkBandwidth() - requiredNetworkBandwidth);
}

Constraint unusedComputer(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
    return constraintFactory.forEach(CloudComputer.class)
            .ifNotExists(CloudProcess.class, equal(Function.identity(), CloudProcess::getComputer))
            .penalize("unusedComputers",
                    HardSoftScore.ONE_HARD,
                    computer -> computer.getCpuPower() + computer.getMemory() + computer.getNetworkBandwidth());
}
```

I have also removed the cost constraint because it doesn't make sense in this context.

However, i dont want the planner to dump all the avalible processes into computers.

Meaning, if all the computers are already full and there are unused processes I would like them to stay that way and not be forced to add more overfill penalty to a computer.

I guess this can be done by somehow ignoring the init penalty but I can't seem to understand where or how to implement that idea.

I also thought about adding a "dummy" computer entity that just holds processes with no penalty (the planner will still fill regular computers because not filling them will resault in a soft penalty) but it seems like a lot of work and requires big changes to almost every part of the project so if there is a way to implement the first idea it would be preferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're describing is called [over-constrained planning](https://www.optaplanner.org/docs/optaplanner/latest/repeated-planning/repeated-planning.html#overconstrainedPlanning).
Most likely, you are looking for [nullable variables](https://www.optaplanner.org/docs/optaplanner/latest/repeated-planning/repeated-planning.html#overconstrainedPlanningWithNullableVariables).
Your idea with a dummy is called a "[virtual value](https://www.optaplanner.org/docs/optaplanner/latest/repeated-planning/repeated-planning.html#overconstrainedPlanningWithVirtualValues)".

Comment: If i may ask a followup question.
I wanna give the planner an initial state, where processes are allocated to computers and then give a medium penalty for changes from that initial state. Any ideas on how I should approach this?  (medium score can be done by 3-level score obviously)

Comment: The previous question can be reduced to the next question:
Can Planning variables be initialized for the solver or will this cause an undefined behavior? if they can be initialized is there an example on how to do it?

Comment: Look up "continuous planning" in the docs.

Comment: Last question: how do I implement a constraint for unassigned values?
Iv'e tried just checking if the planning variable is null, but it seems that using the constraint factory with foreach(CloudProcess.class).....
doesn't iterate over nulled planning entities or something. if you prefer that i'll create a new question with more details i can do that aswell.

Comment: Normally a different question would be preferred, but since it's already here, you're looking for forEachIncludingNullVars().

Comment: You are so good at what you are doing i am speechless. Thank you!

Comment: It's a group effort, but thank you anyway. :-)